WPF Datagrid: Change datagridcell foreground color
I've DataGrid control that ItemSource is bound to a DataTable. DataTable data is retrieved from the Oracle database via SQL query.
Column names and count are not fixed, so I set AutoGenerateColumns="True" .
I want to set cells Foreground color to green if value of it is '✔'.
I tried to pass the cell value to the value converter class via cell content.But content is always empty.
These are XAML codes:
     <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ExcelCellStyle}"
       x:Key="ModifiedExcelCellStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource cellConverter}}"
          Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
    
     <DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="3"
               Margin="0,0,5,5"
               ItemsSource="{Binding DtSub, Mode=TwoWay}"
               Style="{DynamicResource ExcelStyle}"
               RowStyle="{DynamicResource ExcelRowStyle}" 
               CellStyle="{DynamicResource ModifiedExcelCellStyle}"
                ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyleVertical}"
               AutoGenerateColumns="True">
         
    
     </DataGrid>

This is converter class:
public class CellValueToBoolenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string cellValue = (string)value;   
        if(cellValue.Equals('✔'))
            return true;
        return false;

    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

This is ViewModel:
private DataTable dtSub;

public DataTable DtSub
{
    get { return dtSub; }
    set
    {
        dtSub = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void GetDatas()
{
    DtSub = sqlHelper.GetOperationsData();
}



you check equality of string and char. how do you expect to get true?

The problem is Content.Text value is always empty.  https://ibb.co/xJ276Sv

The DataGridCell.Content is derived from ContentControl.Content and its type is System.Object. It does not have Text property.

@emoacht thanx for attention. So is my approach is wrong? how can i reach cell value? Or how can I change foreground color  of the cell text to green?

It depends on your data model and styles that you haven't shown.

@emoacht I edited the post. DataTable data is retrieved from the Oracle database via SQL query. There is no model class.

I am afraid you need to define a CellStyle for each column where you bind to the actual column that holds the value.
You can do this dynamically by handling the AutoGeneratingColumn event for the DataGrid:
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    Style style = new Style()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell),
        BasedOn = TryFindResource("ExcelCellStyle") as Style
    };
    DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger()
    {
        Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { Converter = TryFindResource("cellConverter") as IValueConverter },
        Value = true
    };
    trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green));
    style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    e.Column.CellStyle = style;
}

But you cannot use a generic Style for all columns.
You should also fix your converter implementation:
object IValueConverter.Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
    value is string s && s.Equals("✔");

